# prevent scroll bar after zooming image in bottom of page

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have an image , when hover on it , it will scale with  property transform : scale(3,3) (scale from center of image), but when the image in the bottom of page, scroll bar appear when I hover on image because it's scaling . Is there any way  to auto scale it with direction from bottom to top (cause I don't want to see scroll bar) when the img is in bottom of page

Comment: What you can do is, you can give a transform-origin to the bottom image. transform-origin: bottom center;

Comment: oh, thanks a lot , that is what I looking for